# sum of Dynamic fields

Tags: prometheus, promql

I need to summarize my VMs by VM name prefix. All my VMs have prefixes like "customername_IIS01", "customername_IIS02", "customernameN_SQL". I need to write a promQL query to sum all customer's metric by customername. But of course when a new customer comes, it needs to get its name by query.

Example:
this is a metric that i need to collect. I can get it by "**vmware_vm_cpu_usagemhz_average{vm_name=~"customer01.+"}**" Customer can go 100 or more and it is changing dynamicly. What is correct way to get this information by promQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the label to create an additional label `customer` containing the name of the customer deduced from the prefix.

This can be done in Prometheus config using [#metric_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs):

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [vm_name]
    regex: ^([^.]+)\..*$
    target_label: customer
    replacement: $1
```

If you don't have access to promteheus config, or if you prefer doing it at query time for whatever reason, you can use [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) to create the label in the query. If your query comes more complicated it is quickly awkward and unreadable.

```
 label_replace({__name__=~"vmware_vm_.*"}, "customer", "$1", "vm_name", "^([^.]+)\..*$")
```

Comment: I tried to add metric_label_configs under related job definition. Your regex could not return needed data but I changed it with ^([^_\t]+).* then I got "customer" on related metric(vmware_vm_cpu_usagemhz_average). But not all values has "customer" field, is it normal?

Comment: Thanks @Michael Doubez, unfortunately Prometheus did not accept its regex and gave error.  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96NHn.png)

Comment: You are missing a ". I'll fix the expression. I couldn't proof the expression, it is an example :).  If values don't have the label `vm_name` or if the pattern is wrong, you'll get an empty value. You will have to adapt the pattern.